# Arduino to Python problem with unicode conversion to integer

Tags: python, unicode, types, arduino, type-conversion

Python 3 …. default is utf-8 ……..
Arduino (C++) sends numbers over the serial monitor to Python.  I want the numbers from C++ as numbers;  I sort the by size and put them in a SQLite datbase as integers.
In_data = int (in_data)      #. (it has worked but I changed computers (Windows to Mint) and now it gives me an error)
print type (in_data)  #gives   “Unicode”.
I think the Unicode includes spaces or something.  I tried treating  in_data as a string and got an error.

(data_object.inWaiting()>0)
    unix = (datetime.datetime.now())
    in_data = data_object.readline().decode('ascii') #this last part is to pull out the extra junk.
   # print (type(in_data)) #  this is 'unicode" whatever that is  (the print works)

```
print (in_data[0])######DID NOT WORK
print (in_data[1])
print (in_data[2])
print (in_data[3])
print (in_data[4])
print (in_data[5])
print (in_data[6])
print (in_data[7])
print (in_data[8])
print (in_data[9])
print ()
lstrip(in_data)   ###THIS DID NOT WORK
rstrip(in_data)

print (in_data)  ##  this goes out to the python monitor;  every number
print type(in_data)#  this works and tells me it is 'unicode'
```

This has worked:  in_data = int (in_data) and the integer logic in Python worked.
Now it gives me an error.  I think that the field includes a space. "Let's treat it as a string and take out the space."  Did not work. "lstrip()' and 'rstrip()' seemed promising, but no.

Comment: What's the output of the error message?

Comment: you need to encode the unicode...unicode_string.encode('utf-8')  unicode is asbtract representation of alphabet...concrete representation come with encoding thus encode('utf-8')

Comment: code is 
    (data_object.inWaiting()>0)
       in_data = data_object.readline().decode('ascii') #this last part is to pull out the extra junk.
    print (type(in_data)) #  this is 'unicode" whatever that is  (the print works)
    in_data=int(in_data)
    
   the error is [ValueError:invalid literal for int() with base 10:] on the above line
I added [in_data.encode(‘utf-8’)]  no error, but same issue

Comment: I took out the [decode ascii]  I added a new line  [in_data.strip() and it all now works fine. That is:  the values are sorted by size and put into the SQLite database.  There is final confusion:  why would a Linux OS perform so differently.  How could the old configuration have worked for almost a million db lines with no problem.  anyway

Comment: (data_object.inWaiting()>0)
    unix = (datetime.datetime.now())
    in_data = data_object.readline().decode('ascii')
    print (type(in_data)) 
    in_data = decode.in_data('utf-8')
    print (type(in_data))

Comment: this issue is not going away.  I am faced with monstrous programming issues and just want to move forward with this one.  The Python receives the integers from Arduino (C++)   as <Unicode>.,  I need the line or possibly two lines that will make the integers into integers.  This will enable me to sort them before putting them in an sqlite3 database.

Comment: I now have six inputs.  Flat file into sqlite3; unix time and number.    The data goes into the sqlite3 as <Unicode>, but the Python pulls them out as <str>, easily converted to <float>. This worked, but the data is a mess and the specific ID of the six inputs was not perfect and causing a problem.  In C++ (the Arduino microcontroller) I added 10 million to stream one, 20 million to stream two etc.  Good idea.  And now I should be able to sort the number from the get-go.  hence, I am back where I started.  My github repository:  https://github.com/mrphysh?tab=repositories

Comment: I added this line:         in_data = in_data.encode('utf-8')